# How does one define synonymous options in style/class files?

Tags: packages, options

I want to be able to pass two options to a package (actually, a class) and have them be the same.  What's the best way to do this?

That is, I want:

```
\documentclass[norsk]{myclass}
```

and

```
\documentclass[bokmal]{myclass}
```

to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting TH.'s comment to Joseph's answer as an answer as it also works.  (CW as it's TH.'s answer.)

`synonymous.sty` contains:

```
\ProvidesPackage{synonymous}
\newcommand{\synonymous}{Hello world}
\DeclareOption{a}{%
  \renewcommand{\synonymous}{Greetings Earthlings}}
\DeclareOption{b}{\ExecuteOptions{a}}
\ProcessOptions
```

whilst `synonmyous.tex` is:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[a]{synonymous}
\begin{document}
\synonymous    
\end{document}
```

Changing the `a` to `b` has no visible effect on the outcome.

Answer (score 8):

It partly depends on how you implement them internally. If the two options set some kind of flag, then it would be easiest to code them by hand

```
\newif\if@mypkg@norsk
\DeclareOption{norsk}{\@mypkg@norsktrue}
\DeclareOption{bokmal}{\@mypkg@norsktrue}
```

If the code is more complex then it might be easiest to write a macro to do the job

```
\newcommand*\mypkg@option@norsk{
   % Code here
}
\DeclareOption{norsk}{\mypkg@option@norsk}
\DeclareOption{bokmal}{\mypkg@option@norsk}
```

Comment: Or I guess I could combine the two: after the options are executed, do `\if@mypkg@norsk code \fi`.  (Was hoping for a more elegant method, though.)

Comment: Does `\DeclareOption{bokmal}{\ExecuteOptions{norsk}}` not work?

Comment: Fair point: should do I think

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew: There is a potential danger with the following solution: endless back-linking in not-so-complex situations. You need a flag to avoid that. See the macro `\XKV@replacepointers` in the xkeyval package.

```
\DeclareOption{a}{%
  \renewcommand{\synonymous}{Greetings Earthlings}}
\DeclareOption{b}{\ExecuteOptions{a}}
```

Comment: It's somewhat confusing to have an _answer_ start with "@Andrew". (Also, I don't quite understand what you're writing about "endless back-linking in not-so-complex situations". Your 3 lines of code are not complex ... Maybe you can expand a bit?)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to make a comment, but the markup of the code wasn't clear enough. So I turned it into a quasi-answer. I hope the following is clear. Consider `\DeclareOption{a}{\renewcommand{\synonymous}{Greetings Earthlings}\ExecuteOptions{c}} \DeclareOption{b}{\ExecuteOptions{a}}  \DeclareOption{c}{\ExecuteOptions{b}}`.